# Explain the third parameter of the ‘cover’ function of the ‘terra’ library in r

Tags: r, terra

I used terra to implement the following process, read a large raster image, then read a smaller area of the vector file, and cropped, cropped the raster image to do some calculations.

```
library(terra)

ndvi <- rast(file.path(file_path,'ndvi.tif'))
vect <- vect(file.path(file_path,'plot.gpkg'))

ndvi_cropped <- crop(ndvi,vect,mask = TRUE)
ndvi_small <- 0.57*exp(2.33*ndvi_cropped)
```

I want to replace the value at the corresponding position in the big raster with the calculated value, regarding the replacement value I only found the cover function, but every time I run it directly, it will error.

```
cover(ndvi,ndvi_small)
#Error: [cover] raster dimensions do not match
```

Comment: can you expand `ndvi_small` to the same size as `ndvi` by padding with `NA`s?

Comment: The 'merge' function accomplishes this. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
m <- merge(ndvi_small, ndvi)
```